# What are the assumptions underlying the master equation?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

In Reichl, 2016; pg405 the author gives a derivation of the master equation - which I will outline below in my own words:

> - We start with:$$P(n,t+\Delta t)=\sum_m^M P(m,t)P(n,t+\Delta t\mid m,t)\tag{$\star$}$$
> - We then Taylor expand $P(n,t+\Delta t\mid m,t)$ as a function of $\Delta t$ to get: $$ P(n,t+\Delta t\mid m,t)=\delta_{m,n} \left[
>   1-\Delta t \sum^M_{l=1} w_{m,l}(t)\right]+w_{m,n}(t)\Delta t+\ldots$$
>     where we have enforced conservation of probability
> - Sub this back into our expression for $P(n,t+\Delta t)$ , rearrange and take the limit as $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$ gives: $$\frac{\partial
>   P(n,t)}{dt}=\sum_m^M\left[ P(m,t) W_{m,n}(t)-P(n,t)
>    w_{n,m}(t)\right] $$

However many sources (including Reichl) hint at a restriction to Markovian process. Given that ($\star$) is simply true and everything else seems is standard I cannot see where the Markovian property comes into this - if it does? Please can someone explain this to me.

Comment: I don't think (*) is simply true. I think it being true is what makes a process Markov.

Comment: Your first equation (*) contains the assumption that the system has "no memory" beyond the last step - i.e. that the time evolution of the probability is only dependent on the current value of the probability, and not on the history of the system.

Comment: @ThePhoton I disagree.  All ($\star$) is saying is that the probability you are in $n$ at $t+\Delta t$ is equal to the probability that you where at $1$ at $t$ and are now at $n$ plus the probability you where at $2$ at $t$ and are now at $n$. The fact that a process is Markovian or not does not change the definition of $P(n,t+\Delta t\mid m,t)$.

Comment: @probably_someone See my comment above.

Comment: If the process were not Markovian, there would be terms proportional to $P(m,t-\Delta t)$, $P(m,t-2\Delta t)$, $P(m,t-3\Delta t)$, etc. The fact that this initial expression does _not_ depend on any additional history of the system is the definition of a Markovian process.

Comment: @probably_someone So you are saying that if you given the probability that you are in a state $m$ at time $t$ for all $m$ and the probability that you go from state $m$ to state $n$ in time $\Delta t$ - you cannot work out the probability you are in state $n$ at $t+\Delta t$.  It would be helpful if you could write down the general formula for a non-Markovian process.

Comment: Since there is a staggering variety of stochastic processes which are not Markovian, with many different types of dependence on the particular history of the system, it's not likely that such a general formula exists. At the very least, I don't know of one; non-Markovian processes are typically studied like PDEs, in that a lot of work is put into studying one particular case at a time.

Comment: @probably_someone Sorry to keep pushing this - but ($\star$) is derived from two facts, that $P(n,t+\Delta t\mid m,t)P(m,t)=P(n,t+\Delta t; m,t)$ (which is a definition) and that $\sum_m P(n,t+\Delta t; m,t)=P(n,t+\Delta t)$. So this last equation is not valid for non-Markovian processes? (here $P(n,t+\Delta t;m,t)$ is the probability at $n$ at $t+\Delta t$ *and* at $m$ at $t$.)

Comment: This last equation is indeed not valid for non-Markovian processes. It would read $\sum_m P(n,t+\Delta t;m,t)+\textrm{(other terms involving the history of the system)}=P(n,t+\Delta t)$.

Comment: @probably_someone I hope this is OK with you but I have asked a question on MSE about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752914/condition-for-a-markov-process

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification The formula (*) is just Bayes theorem and is completely general, i.e. it is applicable to Markov process, non-Markov process, and what-have-you. See Probability theory by Jaynes.

Comment: @Deep I know - this is what I have being arguing :) and hence the use "($\star$) is simply true" in the question.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification However there is one assumption in writing (*) which is that the events associated with different values of $m$ (in $P(m|t)$) are all mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification "mutually exclusive and exhaustive" in the previous comment. I don't see how Taylor expansion gives you the second expression. This is perhaps where the assumption of Markovian process has been slipped in.